# PyQt5: drawing multiple rectangles using events

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a desktop application using PyQt5 where the user will be able to draw rectangles.

User should be able to select the top-left corner of the rectangle with first mouse click and the bottom-right corner with second mouse click. A rectangle should appear in that location with the perimeter well defined. I created application but have a problem when I draw another rectangle previous rectangle vanishes. I am not able to draw multiple rectangles.

Please find the below code for reference

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Windo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(150,250,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Ammyyy")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('a.jpeg'))

        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 6, Qt.SolidLine))
        qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Windo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw n-rectangles then you must save that information in a list through QRect. On the other hand, the selection of 2 points does not imply that the QRect is valid, for example if the first point is on the right, the second point will not create a valid rectangle so that rectangle has to be normalized. Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(150, 250, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Ammyyy")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("a.jpeg"))

        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()
        self.rectangles = []

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 6, Qt.SolidLine))

        for rectangle in self.rectangles:
            qp.drawRect(rectangle)

        if not self.begin.isNull() and not self.end.isNull():
            qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end).normalized())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        r = QRect(self.begin, self.end).normalized()
        self.rectangles.append(r)
        self.begin = self.end = QPoint()
        self.update()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```